# Подсветить поднимающийся элемент списка

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Имеется список отделов, формируемый при помощи Vue.js:

```
<ul class="vue-block">
    <li v-for="(department, index) in departments">
        <span class="department-name">{{department.name}}</span>
        <button @click="up(index)" class="up">up</button>
        <button @click="down(index)" class="down">down</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

В списке имеются кнопки, позволяющие перемещать элементы списка вверх и вниз

```
<script>

    var vm = new Vue({
        el: '.vue-block',
        data: {
            /* отделы добавляются аяксом */
            departments: [] // [{id: 1, name: 'Экономический'}, {...},...]
        },
        methods: {
            /* поднимаем */
            up: function(index) {
                if(index === 0) return
                var prev = this.departments[index-1]
                this.departments[index-1] = this.departments[index]
                this.departments.splice(index, 1,prev) // splice для реактивности
            },
            /* опускаем*/
            down: function(index) {
                // pass
            },
        }
    })
</script>
```

Как сделать, чтобы поднимаемый отдел на некоторое время подсвечивался(добавлялся фон к элементу, допустим на 1 сек.) т.к. список большой и надо как-то выделить поднимающийся/опускающийся отдел. Раньше все работало на jquery по таймауту, но список сильно усложнился и управление перенесено на Vue

Comment: Можно вынести отдельно name элемента, а в цикле проверять совпадение mame посвечиваемого элемента. Отдельно в timeout через секунду занулить этот name. Если нужно, могу привести пример кода.

Comment: @Idushii Добавил в data свойства timeout и buble(здесь хранится id отдела), а в метод up добавил
`var context = this
context.buble = this.departments[index].id
clearTimeout(context.timeout)
context.timeout = setTimeout(function() {
context.buble = null})`

Comment: @Idushii Поднимающейся строке добавляется класс info со стилями:
.info {
   transition: 1s ease-in-out
}

Comment: @Idushii Теперь все работает почти как нужно. Поднимающаяся строка должна резко подсветиться и плавно потухнуть, а она плааавно начинает подсвечиваться и плавно тухнет. Как так сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Можно вынести отдельно id элемента, а в цикле проверять совпадение mame посвечиваемого элемента. Отдельно в timeout через секунду занулить этот id. 
Если нужно, могу привести пример кода.

2) Можно сделать так:

- добавить подсветку
- добавить класс с плавным изменением цвета.

Т.е. у Вас будет уже две переменные: первая это id элемента, а вторая - признак того, что цвет уже изменился. Для того, чтобы поставить задержку на перерисовку DOM можно использовать [$nextTick](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick).

Возможно, проще будет путь через [тег transition](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0), но его использование  может быть не самым простым делом.

В комментарии ответ уже не влез))

Comment: Сейчас пример сделаю на transition

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Nic34/bu348mcx/ к сожалению, как сделать именно так, как вы описали, я не смог. Только так.

Comment: Магия!) Объединил Ваш вариант со своим - получилось идеально! Спасибо большое!

Comment: То, что у меня получилось в итоге: https://jsfiddle.net/Nic34/hx0uq8La/

Comment: __   Пожалуйста))

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов - использовать `animation`.

```js
function highlight() {
  block.classList.remove('highlight');
  setTimeout(() => block.classList.add('highlight'), 0)
}
```

```css
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 16px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.highlight {
  animation: hanim 1s;
}

@keyframes hanim {
  from {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  to {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="block" class="block"></div>
<button onclick="highlight()">highlight</button>
```